# /bin/sh: tar: command not found when docker build

Tags: docker

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:6.6


RUN cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai /etc/localtime
RUN echo ZONE=\"Asia/Shanghai\" > /etc/sysconfig/clock


RUN rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo 
#COPY CentOS6-Base-163.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/
RUN yum clean all



RUN groupadd -g 2500 canal; useradd -u 2501 -g canal -d /home/canal -m canal
RUN echo canal:De@2018er | chpasswd; echo root:dockerroot | chpasswd


RUN yum -y update && yum -y install wget vi openssl.x86_64 glibc.x86_64 tar tar.x86_64 inetutils-ping net-tools telnet which file
RUN yum clean all


COPY jdk-8u291-linux-x64.tar.gz /opt
RUN tar -zvxf /opt/jdk-8u291-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt && \
        rm -rf /opt/jdk-8u291-linux-x64.tar.gz && \
                        chmod -R 755 /opt/jdk1.8.0_291 && \
                                        chown -R root:root /opt/jdk1.8.0_291
RUN echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_291' >> /etc/profile                       
RUN echo 'export JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre' >> /etc/profile
RUN echo 'export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JRE_HOME/lib:$CLASSPATH' >> /etc/profile
RUN echo 'export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin:$PATH' >> /etc/profile
RUN source /etc/profile


RUN yum install kde-l10n-Chinese -y
RUN yum install glibc-common -y
RUN localedef -c -f UTF-8 -i zh_CN zh_CN.utf8
ENV JAVA_HOME /opt/jdk1.8.0_291
ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
ENV LANG zh_CN.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL zh_CN.UTF-8


ADD canal-server /home/canal/
RUN chmod 755 /home/canal/bin


WORKDIR /home/canal/bin
RUN chmod 777 /home/canal/bin/restart.sh
RUN chmod 777 /home/canal/bin/startup.sh
RUN chmod 777 /home/canal/bin/stop.sh
RUN chmod 777 /home/canal/bin/config.sh
CMD  /home/canal/bin/config.sh
```

when I using this command to build docker image:

```
docker build  -t canal/canal-server:v1.1.5 .
```

shows this error:

```
~/Software/canal-server ⌚ 15:31:31
$ docker build  -t canal/canal-server:v1.1.5 .                                                                                                                                                    ‹ruby-3.0.0›
[+] Building 4.3s (15/30)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.87kB                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/centos:6.6                                                                                                                                             1.3s
 => [ 1/26] FROM docker.io/library/centos:6.6@sha256:32b80b90ba17ed16e9fa3430a49f53ff6de0d4c76ad8631717a1373d5921fa26                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 6.60kB                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/26] RUN cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai /etc/localtime                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/26] RUN echo ZONE="Asia/Shanghai" > /etc/sysconfig/clock                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [ 4/26] RUN rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [ 5/26] RUN yum clean all                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [ 6/26] RUN groupadd -g 2500 canal; useradd -u 2501 -g canal -d /home/canal -m canal                                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [ 7/26] RUN echo canal:De@2018er | chpasswd; echo root:dockerroot | chpasswd                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [ 8/26] RUN yum -y update && yum -y install wget vi openssl.x86_64 glibc.x86_64 tar tar.x86_64 inetutils-ping net-tools telnet which file                                                             0.7s
 => [ 9/26] RUN yum clean all                                                                                                                                                                             0.4s
 => [10/26] COPY jdk-8u291-linux-x64.tar.gz /opt                                                                                                                                                          1.2s
 => ERROR [11/26] RUN tar -zvxf /opt/jdk-8u291-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt &&         rm -rf /opt/jdk-8u291-linux-x64.tar.gz &&                         chmod -R 755 /opt/jdk1.8.0_291 &&                    0.5s
------
 > [11/26] RUN tar -zvxf /opt/jdk-8u291-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt &&         rm -rf /opt/jdk-8u291-linux-x64.tar.gz &&                         chmod -R 755 /opt/jdk1.8.0_291 &&                                         chown -R root:root /opt/jdk1.8.0_291:
#15 0.489 /bin/sh: tar: command not found
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c tar -zvxf /opt/jdk-8u291-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt &&         rm -rf /opt/jdk-8u291-linux-x64.tar.gz &&                         chmod -R 755 /opt/jdk1.8.0_291 &&                                         chown -R root:root /opt/jdk1.8.0_291]: exit code: 127
(base)
```

I have tried to install `tar` or `tar.x86_64` before using the command but still not work. what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Does `/opt` exist in the container?   whether it does or not, you should always add a trailing `/` when the destination of a cp or mv etc is a directory, just in the case the directory doesn't exist yet.   e.g. `COPY jdk-8u291-linux-x64.tar.gz /opt/` and `tar .... -C /opt/`.   Also, you don't need the `-r` option on the `rm -rf /opt/jdk-8u291-linux-x64.tar.gz`.  It's a file, there's nothing to recurse.  `rm -f` is all that's needed (or even just `rm` as rm won't have been aliased in the container).

Comment: I upgrade the centos image version to 7, maybe the lower version of centos did not have a valid repo url to download tar package. @cas

Comment: I wasn't commenting on your tar problem, if I had been doing that I would have written an answer ( but that seems to have been answered correctly already - i.e. don't delete the repo definitions before trying to install packages).  I was commenting on some of the obvious minor errors in your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2):

Place this line in your docker file, *before* you remove the repos:

```
RUN yum -y update && yum -y install wget vi openssl.x86_64 glibc.x86_64 tar tar.x86_64 inetutils-ping net-tools telnet which file
```